# Bootstrap modalbox refresh on close

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Modalbox of Twitter bootstrap, which is a flexible plugin, but I can't refresh the page after close the modal box.

My code is:

```
 <a href="inc/orders.php?id_ord=<?php echo $row_orders['ir_ord']; ?>" class="btn    btn-success" id="moo" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal">aprobbate order</a>
```

Call fine the IFRAME modalbox. I tried this js for refresh when close the modalbox but without results:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
     location.reload(); 
   })
  </script>
```

Comment: Is it triggering at all? Because that might not be the correct event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much. I solve adding in Iframe´s page this js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#moo').click(function(){
     location.reload();
   });
 });
</script>
```

Adding atribuute Id="moo" in my button, work fine. On press the button CLOSE, reload page.

Comment: Could you up my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting until the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
        window.location.reload(); 
    });
});
```

You can also try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#myModal[data-dismiss="modal"]', function () {
        window.location.reload(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I solve adding in Iframe´s page this js: